# How can I solve an error where a default export is not found at the file level I specified?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to build a simple Covid-19 tracker using an API and React tocreate interactive displays. However, when I try to run the project, I keep getting this error:

[image]

Here is my App.js folder, where it appears I am importing them correctly:
[App.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EshMe.png)

Lastly, here is my index.js file in my components folder, which is where I am exporting the files:[index.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6akKv.png)

I am not sure what the problem is. Initially, I thought it may be a problem with how it's navigating to the files, but when I change that, nothing appears to be different, and the error persists. Would anyone be able to help?

Here is what my file structure looks like for reference: [file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVsdO.png)

Comment: Please use appropriate code blocks for sharing code snippets versus images alone. Same for errors. Images aren't searchable nor easy to copy/paste text from. Voting to close as issue is caused by typo in index.js file, "defualt" versus "default".

Answer (score 2):

You have typo in word "defualt"

Answer (score 0):

you should try:

```
import {default as Cards} from "./Cards/Cards";
```

You misspelled 'default'